# How to use text processing or data standardisation methods to bucket fields that mean the same thing and map it to the key of below dictionary

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-science, string-matching

I am trying to find a quick and effective way of mapping the values of the below dictionary to the key of dictionary in a given textbody.

Maybe something along the lines of String matching, fuzzy string matching, NER/Topic modelling maybe, other NLP or general clever text processing techniques that can be used to find related words in the text and then map it to the key of the dictionary. Thanks a ton!

Example: If I find some other form of "Fuel consumption" like "fuel_consumption" or "fuel-consumption" or maybe the order of words could be different but I should be able to find related keyword from the dictionary.

So far I have tried a combination of Regex and Fuzzy String Matching to get work done. But I am looking for a better solution. That will also be able to tell keywords that mean the same thing. Maybe pre trained word embeddings for cars, sports cars, F1/related races and drivers and related text data would help to encode the meaning of these words somehow and will bucket and map two/more related words to the same key of the above dictionary.

The data can come from different websites so different websites display the same info of car specifications/engine using different names/formats. This program should be able to bucket and map these related fields that mean the same thing coming from different websites. Any Data Standardisation techniques for words/text data could also work probabaly.

I am looking for you folks help to point me in the right direction to achieve better results at this task! Thanks a ton!

**P.S. Please tell me if anyone knows any resources for pre-trained word embeddings for cars, sports cars, F1/related races and drivers and related text data.**

```
"fuel_consumption_and_emissions" : {
    "Fuel consumption": ["Fuel consumption***"],
    "CO2 Emissions": ["CO2 Emissions ***", "CO2 emissions***"],
    "Emissions": ["Emissions***"]
},

# Co2 emissions
"co2_emissions" : {
    "Combined": ["Combined", "Combined* (ECE+EUDC) (g/km)", "Combined ECE*", "Combined (ECE+EUDC)*",'Combined Consumption:'],
    "Low": ["Low",'Low Consumption:'],
    "Mid": ["Mid",'Medium Consumption:'],
    "High": ["High",'High Consumption:'],
    "Extra High": ["Extra High", "Extra high", "Extra  High",'Very High Consumption:'],
    "Note": ["Note"],
    'Fuel Efficiency: Weighted Combined (WLTP)': ['Fuel Efficiency: Weighted Combined (WLTP)'],
    'CO2 Emissions: Weighted Combined (WLTP)': ['CO2 Emissions: Weighted Combined (WLTP)'],
    'CO2 Emissions EU WLTP': ['CO2 Emissions EU WLTP', 'CO2 Emmissions EU WLTP'],
    'CO2 Emissions EU NEDC': ['CO2 Emissions EU NEDC'],
    'Co2 Emissions:' : ['Co2 Emissions:'],
    'Power Consumption:' : ['Power Consumption:'],
    'Battery Range:' : ['Battery Range:']
    
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Rephrase/Edit your question.

Comment: I think Regex would do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried regex but Im looking for better approaches to find such words in text and map it to keys. Regex would only find exact matches but I need to find similar words and tag it to same key as well.

Comment: Please tell me if anyone knows any resources for pre-trained word embeddings for cars, sports cars, F1/related races and drivers and related text data.